# TFS - Good practice - more users at one station

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfsbuild

We have one perplexity about current situation with TFS. There are 3 branches: Develop, Main, Production. Also, we have separate station where we are doing versions build and at that station is mapped Main and Production branch. At stations of our programmers are mapped Develop and Main branches and we are doing Merge between these two branches at our local stations, while Merge between Main and Production doing at separate station for versions build.

We have issue because until now, merge at production station were doing with only one shared user and we don't have information which programmer done that work for specific version (we can see merge at Main branch in that period, but we need more accurate information). One solution could be that we do merge at production at our local stations. Other solution can be that each user has own folders at production stations, but we would like to consider is it possible to use same folders at production station for all users??? Now, we get message that folders are already used from other user at same Workspace. Is something like that possible? Do you have suggestions what are good practices in this situation?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post from Grant Holliday seems to provide information on the standard capability of TFS2010 to service Public Workspaces: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/11/08/tfs2010-public-workspaces.aspx:

> The Public Workspaces feature removes this limitation of one user per
>   workspace and **allows multiple users to use the same workspace mappings
>   on a single machine**. Unlocked workspaces are sometimes also referred
>   to as "Shared workspaces", as they can be shared among multiple
>   people.

Comment: Thanks kroonwijk! This is exactly what we needed!